# HTML CSS video inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, video, flexbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<style>
.d1 {
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
}
video {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
</style>
<body> 

<div class="d1">
  <video controls>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

I use a `video` inside a `flexbox` like the above and the code works fine except two points: **1)** The video size does not fit the control line that is below. How can I make it fit? I think it has something to do with the alignment... **2)** I want the `video` to be resized horizontally only. For that, I searched and use `width: 100%` and it works but as I resize it the right part seems to ignore the `margin` that I give it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
```

Add the above styling to the css. Try the snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .d1 {
    background: blue;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  video {
    margin: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="d1">
    <video controls>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```