# Getting two div elements to be in line with each other

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling to get the CSS working for this. I've got an iframe that embeds a YouTube video, I've removed the default width and height of the iframe, and added some CSS to make the player resize responsively while maintaining the aspect ratio of it:

```
@media (min-width:1336px) {
    .customvideoplayer-video-block {
        padding-right: 45%;
    }
}

.customvideoplayer-video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--aspect-ratio, .5625) * 100%);
}

.customvideoplayer-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The padding of 45% was added to reduce the player size on bigger resolutions as the height of the player was exceeding the height of the screen.

The problem is now with a playlist section I added, which is appearing like this (the green outline is the video player and the red outline is the playlist):

[image]

Which is fine for a mobile layout. But for larger screens, I'd like the video player and playlist to appear side by side like this:
[image]

This is the html/php:

```
<div class="customvideoplayer-video-player">
    <hgroup>
        <h1 class="customvideoplayer-block__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <h6 class="customvideoplayer-date"><?php echo get_the_date('j F Y'); ?></h6>
    </hgroup>

    <?php if ($videos = theme('videos')) { ?>
        <div class="customvideoplayer-video-block">
            <div class="customvideoplayer-video-container" style="--aspect-ratio: 9 / 16;">
                <iframe name="videoPlayer" src="<?php echo str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $videos[0]['video_link']); ?>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen class="customvideoplayer-video"></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="customvideoplayer-video-playlist">
                <div class="customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-header-row">
                    <?php if (theme('sponsor_logo')) { ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo theme('logo') ?>" alt="Logo" class="customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-header-logo">
                    <?php } ?>                          
                </div>

                <div class="customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table">
                    <table>
                        <?php foreach( $videos as $video ) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-row"><?php echo $video['video_order_number']; ?></td>
                                <td class="customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-row"><a href="<?php echo str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $video['video_link']) . "?autoplay=1"; ?>" target="videoPlayer"><?php echo $video['video_title']; ?></a></td>
                                <td class="customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-row"><?php echo $video['video_duration']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.customvideoplayer-video-player{
    background-color: #27282c;
    padding: 2em 10%;
}

@media (min-width:1336px) {
    .customvideoplayer-video-block {
        padding-right: 45%;
    }
}

.customvideoplayer-video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--aspect-ratio, .5625) * 100%);
}

@media (min-width: 1921px) {
    .customvideoplayer-video-container {
        padding-left: 30%;
    }   
}

.customvideoplayer-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.customvideoplayer-video-playlist {
    
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffa024;
}

.customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table {
    color: white;
    background-color: #1b1c1f;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-header-row {
    color: white;
    background-color: #1b1c1f;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffa024;
    padding: 10px;
}

.customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-header-row > p {
    margin: 0;
}

.customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-header-logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px
}

.customvideoplayer-video-playlist-table-row {
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I've been searching how to align elements and have tried floating left, displaying inline-block, flex, etc but none have worked. I think because the video player is currently filling 100% of the width of the screen (with or without padding), those options won't work? But I'm not sure how to adjust the size of the video player whilst keeping the aspect ratio.

The next step would be getting the video player height and playlist height to match - is there a way to do this using just html/CSS?

Comment: With pure html/CSS, you need a flexbox setup. If you don't want to change your layout do flex, you can also to this with JS

Comment: @Wimanicesir I don't mind using a flexbox setup assuming I can still change the video player size responsively?

Comment: Yes, check this example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599918/html-css-video-inside-flexbox

Comment: @Wimanicesir that works, thanks